# Realm access from incorrect thread when Observable subscribed on Schedulers.io()

Tags: android, realm, rx-android

I am subscribed on IO scheduler.

```
getObservableItems(itModel).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                onBackpressureBuffer().
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribe(new Observer<List<ItemModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<ItemModel> resultItemModel) {
                    }
                });
```

This is my observable where I am doing Realm transactions

```
private Observable<List<ItemModel>> getObservableItems(ItModel itModel) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            realm = Realm.getInstance(mContext);
            if (itModel != null) {
                ArrayList<String> ids = ProjectUtil.getId(itModel.getRequestUrl());
                DatabaseHelper.saveItemCategory(realm, itModel, ids.get(0), ids.get(1));
            }
            RealmQuery<ItemModel> itemModelRealmQuery = realm.where(ItemModel.class);
            /* Error on below line */
            resultItemModel = itemModelRealmQuery.equalTo("res_id", subCategoryModel.getId()).
                    equalTo("menu_grp_id", subCategoryModel.getMenu_grp_id()).findAll();
            subscriber.onNext(resultItemModel);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are combining `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO()` with `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.

This means that you execute the work on the `io()` thread but try to use the result on the main thread. This currently goes against Realms threading policy as we use Thread confined objects. We have an issue for supporting this use case here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1208

Until then you will either have to copy your Realm data to standard Java objects or do all realm operations on the same thread (by removing subscribeOn/observeOn).

Answer (score -1):

After update `0.87.1`, `Realm` provide `RxJava` support.

```
realm.where(ItemModel.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(new Observer < RealmResults < ItemModel >> () {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(RealmResults < ItemModel > itemModels) {
   System.out.println(itemModels.get(0).getItem());

  }
 });
```

Comment: Same issue, with that, the problem is with .subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO() as sat Christian Melchior